# Map of string and list of integer with apex repeat in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, map

i have one map as following :

```
public lisT<integer> testIntList{get;set;} 
public list<string> departmentsToShow{get;set;}
public map<string,List<Integer>> Dep_listToShow{get;set;}
```

which will show the integer list based on department name.

in visual force page when i write following :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!departmentsToShow}" var="department">
     <apex:repeat value=" {!testIntList}" var="IntVal">
                        {!IntVal} --
 </apex:repeat></apex:repeat>
```

its giving me following output : 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6

tub when i write following :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!departmentsToShow}" var="department">
    <apex:repeat value=" {!Dep_listToShow[department]}" var="IntVal">
                        {!IntVal}
    </apex:repeat> </apex:repeat>
```

its giving me following output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] but i need this output : 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6

i want to loop the list of integer from map. how to do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual content of `Dep_listToShow[department]`? How does the output differ from the objective?

Comment: value will be stored like {"department1" : [1,2,3,4,5,6] , "department2" : [1,2,3]} something like this

Comment: value will be the list of integers.

Comment: So your code appears to be producing the expected output. Can you edit the question to be specific about the problem?

Comment: just edited for what output i want from list of integer in the map.

Comment: Create an attribute which holds list of keys(in your case list of strings - department names) then use `<apex:repeat>` to loop through it. Within the repeat you can get the value you expect. `Dep_listToShow[department]`

Comment: yes i am doing that : "department" is the "var" which is coming from another repeat which loops the department name in Dep_listToShow[department].

Comment: Ah got it. You need another repeat within it as `Dep_listToShow[department]` return a list. so do `<apex:repeat value=" {!IntVal}" var="IntValItem"> {!IntValItem}</apex:repeat>` within what you have already.

Comment: you mean like this??
    <apex:repeat value=" {!Dep_listToShow[department]}" var="intListFprDep">
                            <apex:repeat value="{!intListFprDep}" var="intVals" >{!intVals}--</apex:repeat>                        </apex:repeat>

Comment: its still giving same output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your controller is like this:

```
public List<String> departmentsList{get;set;} //eg. ['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3']
public Map<String,List<Integer>> departmentsMap{get;set;} //eg. 'dep1'=>[1,2,3], 'dep2'=>[4,5,6]
```

And your page is:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!departmentsList}" var="department">
<apex:repeat value="{!departmentsMap[department]}" var="itemNo">
-{!itemNo}-
</apex:repeat>
<apex:repeat>
```

Output should be like:
-1-2-3-4-5-6-

Comment: oh yes, did the same but var name i took duplicate so may be thats why i was getting error just changed variable name and it worked.. thank you very much..